# How to add plugins to my custom wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a WordPress theme by myself since I'm working for the first time in Wordpress I've watched some tutorials about it.

I have page.php header and footer and ofc an index. I insert the content from the pages with this:
`<?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID); ?>`
but I tried the get_post in a while loop with same result..

Everything is fine but when I want to use a plugin I can't add to my page... When I insert the shortcode of it it shows only the shortcode string... There are some plugins where I can click a "view" option and it would show a page with my plugin (for example a calendar) but that page is empty...

When I activate an original theme it works instantly... So I'm sure something is missing from my theme something which can load the plugins but I couldn't find solution for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` function before the head area of the html document is closing? It imports important scripts and styles from wordpress itself (and probably also from the plugins).

See here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/

Before closing the body area, the template should also include

```
<?php wp_footer();?>
```

See here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/

Comment: Thanks ur fast reply! I havent added these codes.. but now I did. I can see the new imports in the dev. toolbar of chrome and I can see it imports the js and css of the plugin but still have only the string of shortcode...

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the specific shortcode that you are using? Is it a shortcode that comes from a plugin or a built-in one?
Does a built-in shortcode work?
You can try for example with this one:
[caption caption="Hello World"  align="alignright" width="300"]

It should display a Hello World string aligned to the right side of the page.

Comment: When a shortcode is not replaced, it usually means that this particular shortcode is not registered within your wp system -> WP does not know how to replace it. It may be the case that a plugin is not installed or activated.

Comment: I tried the shortcode you wrote and it also does not work... 

...but I find this method to get content from WP in php:

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php the_content(); ?>

And with using this the shortcodes are working... maybe "the_content();" function was the key, because as I mentioned in my question.. I tried this already but with only the_post();